# How to process image tag without creating JSOUP Document

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am having an Image tag as String. I need to parse the tag and add class and height and width for the tag. For this, I have used the below JSOUP code.

```
String imgTag = "<img class=\"fit-picture\" src=\"/Downloads/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg\" alt=\"Grapefruit slice atop a pile of other slices\">";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(imgTag);
Elements img = doc.select("img");
for (Element image:img) {
image.addClass("abc");
String styleStr = image.attr("style");
                    boolean setSize = true;
                    if(styleStr != null && !styleStr.isEmpty() && (styleStr.contains("width") || styleStr.contains("height"))){
                        setSize = false;
                    }
                    if(setSize) {
                    String w = image.attr("width");
                    String h = image.attr("height");

                    if(w == null || w.isEmpty()) {
                        image.attr("width",width+"");
                    }
                    if(h == null || h.isEmpty() ) {
                        image.attr("height",height+"");
                    }
                    }
}
String imgrep = doc.body().html();
```

Output:

```
<img class="fit-picture abc" src="/Downloads/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" alt="Grapefruit slice atop a pile of other slices" width="332" height="332">
```

In the above code, is it possible to achieve output without creating a JSOUP document? Like standalone Tag or Element object to achieve the same

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't. You can use [`Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(imgTag)`](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment) instead. It also returns a `Document` but an empty shell and makes sure that the parsed tag is in the body.

You can also skip the document creation like this:

```java
final List<Node> nodes = Parser.parseFragment(imgTag, null, "");
```

but the result is still a List of one node with the following HTML:

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <img class="fit-picture" src="/Downloads/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" alt="Grapefruit slice atop a pile of other slices">
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need JSOUP to add these attribute if you need it as a string.

You do it as below

```java
String imgTag = "<img class=\"fit-picture\" src=\"/Downloads/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg\" alt=\"Grapefruit slice atop a pile of other slices\" height=\""+height+"\" width=\""+ width +"\" >";
```

Comment: I've to parse many image tags. In this case,  some tags will have class name already and some don't. Also, I'll check is there any style attribute with width and height, in this case, I'll not add width and height attribute .

Comment: The code in your question have the img declared as string thats the reason I suggested this answer. If you already have these tags (i.e. not constructed by you in the code) then you have to parse it somehow JSOUP is one of the way to do it.

Comment: In Jsoup, itself is there any way to create Standalone Tag or Element to achieve output